# Finding the appropriate distribution and parameters to fit body-mass index data?

Tags: distributions, fitting, mean, beta-distribution

My problem arises from this situation: I have the mean and standard deviation of body-mass index (BMI) for a given population. Contemporary BMI distributions are not close to a normal distribution, i.e., there is a much 'fatter' tail to the right.

Unfortunately, this is where my statistics knowledge ends. What I would like to be able to do, are the following things:

1. Find a distribution that fits my idea of a BMI distribution more appropriately
   1a.)This distribution would likely need to be bounded (very few people have a BMI <14 or >50)
2. From this distribution, be able to find the area under the curve for a given value

EDIT: With reference to the area under the curve, I am looking for a CDF, so I can find the proportion of the population for a given value of BMI.

From some initial research, it seems like a beta-distribution is potentially what I need. But these seem to need parameters within bounds of 0 and 1?

This was all very straightforward with a normal distribution, however the normal distribution is not nearly an accurate representation of the distribution of BMIs.

Comment: Why do you need the area "under the curve"? (do you actually mean you need the area to the left of the specified value -- i.e. the cdf? What for?)

Comment: I would say that the criterion for using a bounded distribution should be based more on the fact that it is impossible to have a BMI <=0, not that very few people have a BMI <14 or >50 (many distributions would allow for very low frequencies at some values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Body Mass Index data typically look asymmetric (right-skewed). In many cases the tails look normal, but in other cases the right tail is heavier. There are numerous families of parametric distributions that can capture this behaviour (skew-symmetric distributions and two-piece distributions). I recommend the following paper for a review on these:

> [On Families of Distributions with Shape Parameters](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/insr.12055/abstract), M.C. Jones (2014). International Statistical Review.

Nonparametric density estimators can also be easily computed for this kind of data sets as follows (which also shows how to fit a skew normal density):

```
library(sn)
# Simulated data
bmi = rsn(1000,20,3,5)

# histogram and kernel density estimator
hist(bmi,probability=T)
points(density(bmi),type="l",col="red",lwd=2)

# parametric approximation using skew normal

log.lik = function(par){
if(par[2]>0) return( -sum(dsn(bmi,par[1],par[2],par[3],log=T)))
else return(Inf)
}

# MLE 
MLE = optim(c(20,3,5),log.lik)$par

# Fitted skew normal density
fit.den = Vectorize(function(x) dsn(x,MLE[1],MLE[2],MLE[3]))

hist(bmi,probability=T)
curve(fit.den,18,30,add=T,col="blue",lwd=2)
```

- Regarding your comment on "the proportion of the population for a given value of BMI", what you need is a quantile of the fitted distribution, rather than the ROC curve.
- The Beta distribution is not appropriate for modelling BMI data since its support is (0,1), while BMI data is positive, and typically way beyond (0,1).